# What method to use to distribute an algorithm on multiple PCs?

Tags: java, algorithm, networking, implementation

I implemented an algorithm based on this publication http://www.prismmodelchecker.org/bibitem.php?key=KNSW07 and is about probabilistic timed automata. What i need now is to implement a method,  a way to distribute its instances on more PCs so that it will work faster because it is based on time and states so it will take less time to get from a state to another. Multiple computers would resolve the problem faster and get to the answer quicker. Now i do not know a method to do this network connection, i found something about client-server, ocsf, but very abstract,  nothing for sure. Also the algorithm is wrote in java,  so it will be better if you provide information that can be used better with java

Comment: So you expect us to study the paper and come up with a distributed version of the algorithm?

Comment: No, i need an idea of a method to use to distribute any algorithm, i will adapt it to mine. If the method already refers to time or something needed exactly for me its better. I just put the documentation for example purpose, not expecting you to read it

Comment: The problem is i do not know where to start and what method to use

Comment: There is no method to speed up arbitrary algorithms by adding parallelism. In fact some problems are inherently sequential and can't be parallelized at all.

Comment: Tell that to my profesor, he insists to distribute the algorithm on multiple pca so it will work faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google "Distributed computing", "High-Performance Computing Cluster", "DIY Supercomputing: How to build a small Windows HPC cluster", "Build server-cluster-aware Java applications"

Comment: someone said, in a comment above, there is no method in speeding up an arbitrary algorithms. Is it true? also , cluster i think is too big for what i need. what i meant, and maybe i was not too clear about it, is that my final projects works on 2-3 computers, or on some virtual ones ( like i start 3 processes on the same computer just for the purpose of example ) and show to my prof an example which runs on this algorithm and it works ( works means get to the result, because i do not need to make a proof that it is actually working faster as it is - a probabilistic algorithm )

Comment: @Adi: Niklas B mentioned "There is no method to speed up arbitrary algorithms by adding parallelism." It's true. You can learn more by google parallel computing, distributed computing. wikipedia is a good reference.